# Encountering "java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor" upon startup of Jetty

Tags: java, transactions, jetty

I am encountering the exception below when starting up my Jetty server.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No suitable constructor:

```
<New id="tx" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Transaction">| ?  <Arg>utxn</Arg>|?  <Arg>|?    <New class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction"/>|?  </Arg>|?</New>
```

I have included below in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId>
    <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I also have the following in my web.xml.

```
<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>utxn</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.transaction.UserTransaction</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

In jetty-env.xml, I specified the following.

```
<New id="tx" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Transaction">
    <Arg>utxn</Arg>
    <Arg>
        <New class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction"/>
    </Arg>
</New>
```

Any idea on what might be causing the exception?

Answer (score 1):

In your configuration you are trying create instance of class `org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jndi.Transaction` with two arguments: string `utxn` and instance of class `com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction`. 
But class `Transaction` has not such kind of constructor, look at its specification [here](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.9.v20160517/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/plus/jndi/Transaction.html).